# Arrow icon missing in navigation using android maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I am using android map v2 to display routes and show my location.But I am not able to see the arrow icon representing my location like in Google maps.I am only seeing a circle icon out there.Is it due to any latest updates with android maps?I tried placing arrow icon from drawable but in that case when i turn icon is not rotating around.(I tried implementing sensor listener). All I wanted is arrow type navigation icon in android map.Please someone help in this problem.

Comment: You know the arrow is displayed when in motion?

Comment: In my created application,I am not seeing the arrow but at the same time when i open google map application i am seeing the arrow.So if i start moving will arrow appear?Anyways i will check that too and will reply.Thanks for responding.